# AWS migrate using import export

Tags: amazon-s3

I want to migrate my VM from on prem to AWS.
I have exported my VM with OVA format and uploaded into S3, I used AWS cli to import it as an image but i got this error :
**"StatusMessage": "FirstBootFailure: This import request failed because the instance failed to boot and establish network connectivity."** 
how can i solve this problem?
Thanks